# How can I list the current Apache 2 virtual hosts from the command line?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, apache-2.4

I want to to retrieve a list of the virtual hosts which are currently loaded and listening for requests i.e not just grepping the config files.

It looks like `apache2ctl -S` does this but I am not 100% sure if that is just returning what is contained in the config files.

Answer (score 44):

The command `a2query -s` works perfectly for me.

Comment: This was the answer for me +1

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. works the same to list modules and configurations:                                  
 `a2query  [-m [MODULES] -s [SITE] -c [CONF] ]`

Comment: In Red Hat Enterprise or CentOS this command, that lists the virtual hosts which are currently loaded is ```httpd -S``` because the deamon itself is not called Apache, but ```httpd```.

Answer (score 8):

The `apachectl -S` documentation says this

> -S
>   Show the settings as parsed from the config file (currently only shows the virtualhost settings).

So you will only see those virtualhosts that are loaded in the config which is read when httpd starts.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this command:

```
apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

It lists all the enabled websites, the path to the conf file and the port that is used by the website.

Comment: This failed when I tried the command as is. It worked once I used `sudo ...`. I have some SSL settings and it would not find that data/module without using `sudo`. Also I don't think this really answers the question because the user wanted to list the virtual hosts that were active at that time, I'm not totally sure this only lists those (I have too many to tell for sure without verifying everything...)

Answer (score 5):

I didn't found official documentation about it.

The command  `apache2ctl -S` check site-enabled*.conf + httpd.conf files and show you if the syntax is correct and the list of virtual host (and some more informations).

But It doesn't check if virtualhosts are running, you can try to stop your Apache and launch again the command, the result will be the same.

So `apache2ctl -S` result is based on configuration files.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
apache2ctl -S | grep -o -E 'alias (.*)|(namevhost|server) (.*)\s' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Will output the list of configured domains and aliases

Works fine on `Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)`

Comment: I like this, but it's interesting that it (correctly) shows 20 vhosts on my system with 14 unique domain names (because HTTP and HTTPS), while `certbot --apache` lists 14 names that don't entirely match. `apache2ctl` *only* lists the `ServerName` values, skipping the `ServerAlias` (while certbot somehow knew to skip the vhosts I had explicitly broken by prepending the domain name with **xxx_**)

Comment: Apachectl -S shows the running configuration. Could it be that not all vhosts have le cert?

Comment: Yes, for example dev domains that can have internal certs or none

Answer (score 0):

a2query -s only lists the name of site.conf files. I notice this because I tried it and I have a config file with more than one vhost enable in it and it didn't list any of them.

Comment: The question in the thread is how to list the virtualhosts configuration files in Apache, and it was already answered in the first answer by vishalknishad.

A TIP PRO, before giving an answer, first checks if the question has already been answered, so that your contribution is meaningful and the answer is not repeated.

What you mention is true the `a2query -s` command only lists enabled configurations, if you want to have multiple configurations
sites.conf you must enable them with the command `a2ensite site.conf` https://asciinema.org/a/632193

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/573198)